# AppEngine Python project moved to Ubuntu from Windows will no longer run

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Since moving from Windows to Ubuntu (and setting up AppEngine, AppEngine Launcher, Python 2.5), my AppEngine projects will no longer run properly.

Here is what's thrown back from any file when trying to browse the app in my web browser (running locally through dev_appserver.py), for example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3211, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3154, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 527, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2404, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2314, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2205, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    handler_path, cgi_path, import_hook)
  File "/home/mike/AppEngine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2136, in LoadTargetModule
    module_code = compile(source_file.read(), cgi_path, 'exec')
  File "/home/mike/Projects/..removed project name ../Site/main/main.py", line 1
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp

^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea where I start with this? I have had a fiddle but have no idea what's going on. Is this to do with the different encoding formats or something between Windows and Linux. I'm pretty clueless about that kind of thing...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check your line endings to make sure they are Unix style, and no longer DOS style.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that was indeed the problem. I should have tried that kind of thing myself first but I Wasn't too sure. You should post your answer as an actual answer so that I can mark it as correct :) For anybody else interested I used "flip" (Google it) to convert a couple of files for testing, I'll now convert all files as everything seems ok now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your line endings to make sure they are Unix style, and no longer DOS style.